# R: Random Sampling According to Some Constraint

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I have the following data:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

id_sample <- 1:25
id <- sample(id_sample, replace = TRUE, 100)
var_1 = rnorm(100,100,100)
var_2 = rnorm(100,100,100)
var_3 = rnorm(100,100,100)

data = data.frame(id, var_1, var_2, var_3)

my_data =  data.frame(data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(index = row_number(id)))
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$id),]

groups = data.frame(my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(count=n()))

final_data =  merge(x = my_data, y = groups, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

I want to randomly split this data into two datasets of 70%-30% (data_set_A, data_set_B), such that "chronological order is preserved". By this I mean:

- Suppose id = 1 appears 5 times (id = (1,1,1,1,1), index = (1,2,3,4,5)) : data_set_A  could contain index(1,2) and data_set_b could contain (3,4,5)
- But data_set_A could NOT contain index = (1,3,5) and data_set_B contain index (2,4)

I am not sure how to specify this constraint into the random sampling:

```
n <- as.integer(length(final_data[,1])*0.7)
data_70 <- final_data[sample(nrow(final_data),n), ]
data_30 <- anti_join(final_data, data_70)
```

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
final_data$row_number <- rownames(final_data)

data_70 <- final_data %>% group_by(id) %>% slice_sample(prop=.7)
data_30 <- final_data %>% anti_join(data_70, by="row_number")
```